# Resolving Gesture Conflict in SwiftUI: OnDelete in List Not Working with Custom CardView Gesture

Tags: swift, swiftui, gesture, swiftui-list

Description of the Issue:

I am facing an issue in my SwiftUI project where I have a List inside a custom SlideOverView. The List has an onDelete function for swiping to delete items. However, the onDelete gesture seems to be not working or is conflicting with the drag gesture in the CardView. I am looking for a solution to resolve this gesture conflict.

Code:

```
struct CardContent: View {
    public var body: some View {
        
        let testArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
        
        ZStack {
            Text("This is the main view")
            SlideOverView {
                List {
                    ForEach(testArray, id:\.self) { el in
                        Text(el)
                    } .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                        print("Deleted item")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SlideOverView<Content> : View where Content : View {
    
    var content: () -> Content
    
    public init(content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self.content(), modifier: CardView())
    }
}

struct CardView: ViewModifier {
    @State private var dragging = false
    @GestureState private var dragTracker: CGSize = CGSize.zero
    @State private var position: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 250
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2.5)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 5.0)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                    .padding(10)
                content.padding(.top, 30)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
            .scaleEffect(x: 1, y: 1, anchor: .center)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(15)
        }
        .offset(y:  max(0, position + self.dragTracker.height))
        .animation(dragging ? nil : {
            Animation.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 250.0, damping: 40.0, initialVelocity: 5.0)
        }(), value: position )
        .gesture(DragGesture()
            .updating($dragTracker) { drag, state, transaction in state = drag.translation }
            .onChanged {_ in  dragging = true }
            .onEnded(onDragEnded))
    }
    
    private func onDragEnded(drag: DragGesture.Value) {
        dragging = false
        let high = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 250
        let low: CGFloat = 100
        let dragDirection = drag.predictedEndLocation.y - drag.location.y
        if dragDirection > 0 {
            position = high
        } else {
            position = low
        }
    }
}
```

What I've Tried:

Checked for any obvious issues in the gesture implementation in the CardView.
Attempted to implement a custom swipe-to-delete functionality in the list.
Used simultaneousGesture to see if both gestures could work together.
Despite these attempts, the issue persists.

Question:

How can I effectively resolve the gesture conflict between the List's onDelete and the CardView's drag gesture in SwiftUI? Are there any specific SwiftUI patterns or methods to prioritize one gesture over the other, or to ensure they can work simultaneously without conflict?

Comment: This looks like you are reinventing `.sheet(...)` Why not just use `.sheet`?

Comment: @Sweeper because my sheet is always visible at the bottom of the screen (kinda like Apple Maps), you can interact also with the main view, with `.sheet` you can only interact with the content inside `.sheet` and when you tap outside it just closes it

Comment: `sheet` can in fact do all of the things you want. Try Googling each thing you want to do. There should be a stack overflow post for each.